# jQuery UI slider calculations

Tags: jquery, function, user-interface

I have 2 sliders on a page, 1 controls the amount of days and the other controls the amount of money to be loaned.

I have this calculation:

```
    function calculate(){
    var days = $("#days-value").val();
    var amount = $(".loan-amount-value").val();
    var percent = .10;
    var interest = (days * amount * percent)/10;
    var total = parseInt(amount, 10) + parseInt(interest, 10);
    $("#total-repay").val(total);
    $("#interest-fees").val(interest);  
};
```

But it is only working when the page loads. I need it to update when the sliders change. I know I need to call the calculate function every time the slider changes but I am just not sure how to write it. Is this possible?

Here is the rest of the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   


$(function() {     

    var inputValue = $(".loan-amount-value").val();

    $( ".loan-amount-slider" ).slider({
    min: 100,
    max: 500,
    step: 1,
    value: 200,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        //update loan amount value when sliding loan amount slider 
        $(".loan-amount-value").val(ui.value);  
         }
        });  
        //show the loan amount initially
        $(".loan-amount-value").val($(".loan-amount-slider").slider("value"));      
        //when the loan amount changes via user input.. 
        $("#loan-amount-value").change(function(event) {
        //change the slider to that amount  
        $(".loan-amount-slider").slider("option", "value", inputValue); 
        })

    var dayInputValue = $("#days-value").val();

    $( ".days-slider" ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 45,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {    
        //update day when sliding day slider 
        $("#days-value").val(ui.value);
        }
        }); 
        //show the day initially
        $("#days-value").val($(".days-slider").slider("value"));

        //when the day via user input.. 
        $("#days-value").change(function(event) {
        //change the slider to that amount  
        $(".days-slider").slider("option", "value", dayInputValue);
        });

function calculate(){
    var days = $("#days-value").val();
    var amount = $(".loan-amount-value").val();
    var percent = .10;
    var interest = (days * amount * percent)/10;
    var total = parseInt(amount, 10) + parseInt(interest, 10);
    $("#total-repay").val(total);
    $("#interest-fees").val(interest);  
};

});         });
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the issue or at least post the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I have posted a link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `calculate()` function is wrapped incorrectly. Change it to:

```
function calculate() {
    var days = $("#days-value").val();
    var amount = $(".loan-amount-value").val();
    var percent = .10;
    var interest = (days * amount * percent) / 10;
    var total = parseInt(amount, 10) + parseInt(interest, 10);

    $("#total-repay").val(total);
    $("#interest-fees").val(interest);
};
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2e7gq/)**

You might also want to add a call to `calculate` in your other slider's slide function so they both do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a call to calculate in the slide handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function() {   


$(function() {     

    var inputValue = $(".loan-amount-value").val();

    $( ".loan-amount-slider" ).slider({
    min: 100,
    max: 500,
    step: 1,
    value: 200,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        //update loan amount value when sliding loan amount slider 
        $(".loan-amount-value").val(ui.value); 
        calculate(); 
         }
        });  
        //show the loan amount initially
        $(".loan-amount-value").val($(".loan-amount-slider").slider("value"));      
        //when the loan amount changes via user input.. 
        $("#loan-amount-value").change(function(event) {
        //change the slider to that amount  
        $(".loan-amount-slider").slider("option", "value", inputValue); 
        })

    var dayInputValue = $("#days-value").val();

    $( ".days-slider" ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 45,
    step: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {    
        //update day when sliding day slider 
        $("#days-value").val(ui.value);
        calculate();
        }
        }); 
        //show the day initially
        $("#days-value").val($(".days-slider").slider("value"));

        //when the day via user input.. 
        $("#days-value").change(function(event) {
        //change the slider to that amount  
        $(".days-slider").slider("option", "value", dayInputValue);
        });

function calculate(){
    var days = $("#days-value").val();
    var amount = $(".loan-amount-value").val();
    var percent = .10;
    var interest = (days * amount * percent)/10;
    var total = parseInt(amount, 10) + parseInt(interest, 10);
    $("#total-repay").val(total);
    $("#interest-fees").val(interest);  
};

});         });
```